# Can't Access Windows Environment Variable with C#

Tags: c#, windows

I created an installer using WiX.  One thing the installer does is sets an environment variable PLUGIN_DIRECTORY (it's at the system level).

Within some C# code that I have written, I need to access that variable so I can watch a certain directory.  I do this via the following code:

```
FileSystemWatcher water = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PLUGIN_DIRECTORY") + "\\";
```

Unfortunately (and when I debug), all that watcher.Path is set to is "\".

Do I need to reboot after the install?  I wouldn't see why as the variable is already set.  Any other suggestions?  I'm not getting any errors - it's just not watching the right path.

Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure - is the process with the C# code started after the WiX install is finished, or is it started before that point?  For example, is the WiX installer for the plug-in, and the main app is already running?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you had visual studio open when you created the environment variable then I don't know if it will pick it up until you close and restart VS.  When a process is started it inherits the environment variables from it's parent process.  I'm not exactly sure how VS launches an executable after you build it but it probably is a sub process and as a result isn't picking up your new environment variable.

Comment: That was my problem - when I first performed the install, I wasn't correctly responding to events for the FileWatcher (AKA, my app didn't work).  I fixed the app in Visual Studio, but when I tested in Visual Studio, it didn't pick up the new environment variable.  Basically, it was two separate issues.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Same issue for myself. Don't start your project from VS, start it from windows...

Answer (score 3):

The system environment is inherited from parent, after update, other process can't recognized.

We could refresh process environment by load environment from "machine" and save to "process".

```
string SysEnvir = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);

System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", SysEnvir, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Comment: This definitely avoids the whole "need to restart" issue. So glad I found this (and I'm surprised we didn't check the overloads of `GetEnvironmentVariable` sooner).

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, does PLUGIN_DIRECTORY have anything set after the installer has run?

Comment: Yes, it does.  It is set to a path on the local drive (C:\Program Files\MyApp\Plugins)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if I'm terribly wrong I can't confirm this as I do not have a compiler installed.
But you can try to use: 
watcher.Path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("%PLUGIN_DIRECTORY%") + "\";

That is, %PLUGIN_DIRECTORY% instead of just PLUGIN_DIRECTORY.

Hope it was of any help